# KeyCloak Rest API: groups/{id}/members is giving Internal Server Error

Tags: keycloak, jboss-tools

I am using KeyCloak REST API to get the member details of a particular group and as per the [API Guide](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/red-hat-single-sign-on/version-7.0.0/restapi/#_get_users), the REST Call will be like - `https://ip:8666/auth/admin/realms/SURE/groups/81d5ddbf-b380-4a38-9d7a-aaa175d08867/members`. But I am getting 500 Internal Server Error.

But astonishingly, `https://ip:8666/auth/admin/realms/SURE/groups/81d5ddbf-b380-4a38-9d7a-aaa175d08867, https://ip:8666/auth/admin/realms/SURE/groups/81d5ddbf-b380-4a38-9d7a-aaa175d08867/role-mappings` etc are working fine! So only `../members` is giving the problem.

My KeyCloak Server version is 2.1.0.Final.

Is it working for you? I am not sure this is a bug and hence asking it over here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it giving you some trace in the server side when it throws 500?

Comment: Hi @XtremeBiker, thanks a lot for your help - your clue did the trick. I checked for server log and found the following error - `UT005023: Exception handling request to /auth/admin/realms/MyRealm01/groups/9072a231-69cf-4876-ac61-feb30acd06ce/members: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative value (-2) passed to setMaxResults`. Then I googled for the error and found that this is a known issue, we need to pass the optional parameters, i.e. first and max in the query - otherwise KeyCloak will throw the exception. Many thanks for your hint.